# My Bootstrap Modal ANCHOR is not working from within a line item of a menu (navbar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my navbar code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
<li><a href="/modalexample.html#theModal" data-toggle="modal">ex</a></li>
<li><a href="">Another Link here</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is my modal code from my "modalexample.html" page

```
<div class="modal fade text-center" id="theModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
<h1>Modal Example</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-body"> Modal Information Here </div>
<div class="modal-footer"> Footer Stuff Here </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

For some reason unknown to me, I can't get my modal to appear after clicking the link to the page (/modalexample.html#theModal).

Is there a reason why my anchor will not work from within a navbar?

Is there another way that I can write this to make my modal appear?

Notes: In both pages, I have included jquery-2.1.4.min.js and bootstrap.min.js (the jquery script is placed before the bootstrap script).

Also, I have included the link to bootstrap.css stylesheet at the beginning of both pages.

If more of my code is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Why using `/modalexample.html#theModal` ? you can use like this `<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theModal">Launch demo modal</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to fire an modal in another page via href anchor.
you can put a javascript code in modalexample.html to fire the modal when the page is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#theModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that a modal couldn't be opened from another page.